# make string starting with $ a non variable

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between single quote and double quote string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php)

I have some strings which which are made up of random characters including $ sign, this becomes a problem if the string happens to begin with $ as it is treated as a variable, is there some way around this problem?

```
<?php
$variable="$&%51a-notaVariable";
?>
```

Comment: uhh? use single quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer 1: Use single quotes instead of double quotes.

```
$variable = '$&%51a-notaVariable';
```

Answer 2: If you definitely need to use double quotes for whatever reason, you can escape the dollar sign with a backslash.

```
$variable = "\$&%51a-notaVariable";
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I did need to use double quotes so I will use \ . Thanks

Comment: As you are able to concat Strings and vars, there's no need to use " or ' exclusively. I like ' more, because escaped Strings (especially HTML code with attributes) is ugly to read, but there are arguments for both kinds of quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Use single quotes:

```
<?php
   $variable='$&%51a-notaVariable';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - yes. Use `'` instead of `"` as it won't try to parse the characters in the string. :)

Long answer - yes. Note that you'll have to concat strings instead of putting variables "$inline" (or use `sprintf()` & co)... however, all in all, it's a beneficial tradeoff.